# Extracting a zip file in my machne givs me CRC error?

Tags: 12.04, zip, unzip

I have a large zip that contain hundreds of files. I've unzip'ed it in more than one machine and didn't have any problem before. However, for this particular machine (Ubuntu Server 12.04) I keep getting CRC error for some of the files inside my zip. I've unzip'ed the same file on anther machine just to check if the file itself is corrupted, however it seems to be fine.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the same file(s) each time, the zip file probably got corrupted, possibly when transferring to the machine. Confirm the md5sum or sha1sum of the zip file .

If it's random files, you probably have defective hardware. First guess would be bad RAM. You can try memtest86+.

(BTW, if it's bad RAM, you may find that running md5sum multiple times give different checksums.)

Comment: Just did memtest86+ .. and yes, It seems my RAMs caught a flu :)